# Converting a number into Bijective Base 26 string via batch script (A as 0, AA as 27, etc...)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to build a batch script I will use to create a sub directory in the folder it is ran in. The goal is to create one (or more on subsequent uses) folders called "Alternate A", "Alternate B", "Alternate C", etc... I have a rough starting script that can make folders with numerical counts (1,2,3,...) but converting a number to a base 26 string such as seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration#The_bijective_base-26_system) has gotten a little beyond me.

Here is my working batch file.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "folderCount=1"
echo Checking existing "Alternate*" folders...
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /ad "Alternate*"') do (
  set /a "folderCount+=1"
  echo Found folder: %%a
)

:: Check for existing folder collision
if exist "Alternate %folderCount%" (
  echo Folder "Alternate %folderCount%" already exists! Skipping creation.
) else (
  echo Creating folder: "Alternate %folderCount%"
  md "Alternate %folderCount%"
)

endlocal
```

Here is one attempt I made, is output a folder named "Alternate digit".

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "folderCount=1"
echo Checking existing "Alternate*" folders...
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /ad "Alternate*"') do (
  set /a "folderCount+=1"
  echo Found folder: %%a
)

  rem Initialize an empty string for the encoded folder name
  set "alphaNumeration="
  
  rem Convert folderCount to base 26
  set /a num=%folderCount%
  :loop
  set /a digit=num%%26
  set alphaNumeration=%alphaNumeration%%A + %digit%
  set /a num/=26
  if not %num%==0 goto loop
  
  rem Create the folder with the encoded name
  md "Alternate %alphaNumeration%"

:: Check for existing folder collision
if exist "Alternate %alphaNumeration%" (
  echo Folder "Alternate %alphaNumeration%" already exists! Skipping creation.
) else (
  echo Creating folder: "Alternate %alphaNumeration%"
  md "Alternate %alphaNumeration%"
)

endlocal
```

Here is a second attempt I made, this one results in a folder named "Alternate ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "folderCount=0"
echo Checking existing "Alternate*" folders...
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /ad "Alternate*"') do (
  set /a "folderCount+=1"
  echo Found folder: %%a
)

:: Convert to bijective base 26
set "digits=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
set "count=%folderCount%"
set "BB26="

:loop
if %count% LEQ 25 (
  set "remainder=%count%%26"
  set "BB26=%digits%%remainder%%BB26%"
  set "count=%count%/26"
) else (
  set "remainder=%count% MOD 26"
  set "BB26=%digits%%remainder%%BB26%"
  set "count=%count% / 26"
  goto loop
)

:: Check for existing folder collision
if exist "Alternate %BB26%" (
  echo Folder "Alternate %BB26%" already exists! Skipping creation.
) else (
  echo Creating folder: "Alternate %BB26%"
  md "Alternate %BB26%"
)

endlocal
```

Ive been using AI to help me write these and troubleshooting is proving problematic. I understand some of the logic and wrote the original working file myself but have mostly relied on google fu not a true understanding so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the second attempt you made, there is a syntax error. Line 17 should be on line 16, and separated from the existing content of that line by at least one space character.

Comment: great catch, that fix allowed the script to run. It now results in a folder named "Alternate ABCDEF..." containing the whole alphabet. I updated my post to reflect the changes.

Comment: a) think about what `set "BB26=%digits%%remainder%%BB26%"` would do. b) to do math, you need `set /a`

Comment: That is my hang up in understanding the code, just looking at it it seems to me it would simply concatenate all those variables but I don't see the remainder or BB26 come through in the name. 

I assumed there was some special characters initially with the %%, but now that you point it out If the intent to have them do a mathematical operation I don't understand how to have it handle a string. Like I mentioned this was AI assisted so I'm trying to understand it myself.

Comment: For instance, `set "count=%count%/26"` should be `set /a count /= 26` or `set /a count=count / 26`. `set "remainder=%count%%26"` and `set "remainder=%count% MOD 26"`, should be `set /a remainder=count %% 26`. For `set "BB26=%digits%%remainder%%BB26%"` you have a delayed variable expansion issue..

Comment: The used `set` syntax is wrong each time, arithmetic is intended (see `set /?`). That's a typical mistake from AI - I guess that's why AI is banned on this site. It usually creates more trouble than solutions. It *can* give you ideas for how to solve your problem (if you already know the language well enough to spot and correct those errors), but usually the code itself tends to be faulty (especially for batch - it's a bit better at more common languages. But still - don't expect working code from an AI. It happens, but you have to be lucky).

Comment: Oh I had no idea AI was banned here, I hope my use of it didn't violate the guidelines I haven't accessed this account in close to 2 years, my apologies. I understand that AI can often be wrong, Ive been using it as an assistive tool rather than expecting a working output. Just hope it points me in a direction. Good to know it struggles with batch.

Comment: @Compo thanks for your help in correcting those issues in my syntax. Ill look into the delayed variable expansion issue more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm... You just need to *correctly* convert the number to bijective base 26. Here it is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "folderCount=1"
echo Checking existing "Alternate*" folders...
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /ad "Alternate*"') do (
  set /a "folderCount+=1"
  echo Found folder: %%a
)

rem Convert to bijective base 26
set "base26=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
 
rem Initialize an empty string for the encoded folder name
set "alphaNumeration="
  
rem Convert folderCount to base 26
set /a num=folderCount
:loop
set /a num-=1, digit=num%%26
set "alphaNumeration=!base26:~%digit%,1!%alphaNumeration%"
set /a num/=26
if not %num%==0 goto loop
  

rem Check for existing folder collision
if exist "Alternate %alphaNumeration%" (
  echo Folder "Alternate %alphaNumeration%" already exists^! Skipping creation.
) else (
  echo Creating folder: "Alternate %alphaNumeration%"
  md "Alternate %alphaNumeration%"
)
```

You can read about `!base26:~%digit%,1!` syntax and other forms to get the same result (like `call set`) at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

PS - It is somewhat strange that you show a couple of codes that does *not* work, but that you don't know why they don't works because you did NOT write them... IMHO you should not use ChatGPT to write code or, at least, don't say that...  **`:(`**

Comment: This is great! It perfectly solves the problem I was working on and links to a great resource to help me understand why it works and learn even more. Setting this as the answer. I think I will still use my solution simply because Ive already baked in a few other features and its working. 

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up simplifying the solution and got something working. Rather than trying to do a conversion via a math operation I simply stored the alphabet as a variable. I then indexed the variable [see syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) to extract a sub-string of the Nth character, where N is the count. Notably this requires the use of [CALL SET](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) instead for a batch script to parse the variables embedded in the command.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "folderCount=0"
echo Checking existing "Alternate*" folders...
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /ad "Alternate*"') do (
 set /a "folderCount+=1"
 echo Found folder: %%a
)

:: Convert to bijective base 26
set "alphabetUpper=BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
:loop
call set "BB26=%%alphabetUpper:~%folderCount%,1%%"

:: Check for existing folder collision
if exist "Alternate %BB26%" (
 if %folderCount% LEQ 0 (
 echo Maximum alternate folder count reached!
 ) else (
  set /a "folderCount+=-1"
  goto:loop
 )
) else (
 echo Creating folder: "Alternate %BB26%"
 md "Alternate %BB26%"
)
endlocal
```